# Scala ~> (tilde greater than) operator

Tags: scala, operators

I have the following scala class definition (found in a paper), modeling categories:

```
trait Category[~>[_, _]] {
    def compose[A, B, C]
     (f: B ~> C)
     (g: A ~> B)
     : A ~> C
    def id[A]: A ~> A
}
```

can someone explain me what the '~>' means in the Category type parameter, and in the methods return type? 
Or direct me to a resource that explains it...
I'm new to Scala (coming from Java), so forgive me if that's something a scala user should have known...
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`~>` is just the placeholder-name for the type-parameter of `Category`. Like the `T` in `class Option[T]`.

Additionally, Scala syntax allows you to write `B ~> C` as a shorthand for `~>[B, C]`.

Maybe things get clearer, if you rename it:

```
trait Category[Mapping[_, _]] {
  def compose[A, B, C](f: Mapping[B, C])(g: Mapping[A, B]): Mapping[A, C]
  def id[A]: Mapping[A, A]
}
```

Comment: Now it's clearer...I think i will get used to be free to use weird char to name things (unlike Java). I thought in fact that '~>' meaned something special, but it can be replaced by anything as i understand this correctly..Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, it is completely arbitrary (within Scala’s naming rules for identifiers, of course).

Comment: By the way: The reason why an "operator" was chosen, i.e. operator characters instead of letter characters, was the hope that in the domain of category theory ~> easily translates to the concept of a "morphism" (aka "mapping", "arrow", etc.). Usually you should be careful with operators.

Answer (score 1):

This is also used in [Akka streams](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/stream/stream-quickstart.html#broadcasting-a-stream) as the edge operator.