# What exactly ~> operator means in Spray.io?

Tags: scala, spray, scalatest

Reading through some code, but i can't understand the meaning of this operator.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This may help you :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085951/scala-tilde-greater-than-operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this file: https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-httpx/src/main/scala/spray/httpx/TransformerPipelineSupport.scala

It is a custom operator in spray that is similar to `Function1.andThen` used to compose functions but a bit more convenient when used with Futures. It supports chaining these three types of functions:

- `A => B` and `B => C` to `A => C` (same as `andThen`)
- `A => Future[B]` and `B => C` to `A => Future[C]` (similar to `Future.map`)
- `A => Future[B]` and `B => Future[C]` to `A => Future[C]` (similar to `Future.flatMap`)